# User authentication using django and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to **authenticate the user using MySQL** (running on XAMPP).
However, the table in the database has been created, but when I manually add a user and password in the database and then try to authenticate, it shows invalid credentials.

The above task has been successfully done using sqlite3 .

Objectives to be achieved:

A) User authentication using MYSQL

B) Every time the user logs in, the name and date/time of the user login should be reflected in the database.

Here's my code:

models.py

```
 from django.db import models
 from datetime import datetime
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

 # Create your models here.
 class Login(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False) 

    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)



    def __str__(self):                               
        return self.username
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from first_app.forms import CmdForm #view after login
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
#some imports
from django.urls import reverse
import csv
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
#from django.contrib.sessions import serializers

# Create your views here.
def login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('IP form'))
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Please provide valid credentials')
            return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

    else:
        return render (request,"first_app/login.html", context)

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))


@login_required                                
def form_name_view(request):                     #view after login
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'm500^loxdxy2(q^lf4c(xwu%(-)qf4@-c=vc#f#ey!ooiy1zp('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'automation_user',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'first_app.Login'   #custom user model



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

LOGIN_URL = '/first_app/login'

SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 20
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 25
```

I have already gone through various blogs regarding this, but it was in vain.

Please suggest what changes I can make to achieve the above mentioned objective.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you "manually" add the user? You need to save the password as hashed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just for the test i added the username and password manually in database.! will encrypt the password after i achieve the above mentioned objective.

Comment: @DanielRoseman for now can u please suggest what should be possible changes i can make in the code to achieve the objective. thx for reply.!

Comment: Your code is fine. If you add a user manually in the database you need to make sure the password is hashed.

Try adding a user within Django doing `Login.objects.create_user(username='test', password='SecretPassword')` and it should work.

Comment: @Dalvtor but i don't know why.. but i m able to authenticate the user Using sqlite3 but not MYSQL.  :-(          just for sake of information (if you find it relevent) :- my localhost is running on 127.0.0.1:8000 , phpAdmin is running on 127.0.0.1:8001 and mysql is running on 3306

Comment: There is no "for now", and there is no achieving the objective *without* hashing. You need to create users the correct way, which as Dalvtor mentions is to use `create_user` in Django code (or use the admin interface).

Comment: @DanielRoseman watched a tut regarding the suggestion.  do i have to encrypt the password in my models.py itself ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Create your user via `Login.objects.create_user` as suggested, which will take care of hashing the password for you.